# After camera calibration where to apply camera matrix and distortion coefficient values in new application?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I have already used the calibration code provided by `opencv` to calibrate my camera using C++ and everything went OK.

How can I insert the matrix and the parameters there in new application with same camera setup?

Comment: Thanks and other chit-chat should never be part of a question (read the help-tour).

Answer (score 1):

It's depending on the application you develop. OpenCV's [calib3d](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html) module provides you functionalities to:

- derive useful camera characteristics from the output of calibration, i.e. [calibrationMatrixValues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibrationmatrixvalues)
- find an object pose from 3D-2D correspondences by [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) or [solvePnPRansac](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac)
- estimate new camera matrix based on the free scaling parameter by [getOptimalNewCameraMatrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#getoptimalnewcameramatrix)
- use it as an fix parameter of stereo calibration to achieve better results by [stereoCalibrate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate) and `CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` flag
- estimate the rectification matrix for a calibrated stereo camera by [stereoRectify](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify)
- or to transform an image or some points to compensate lens distortion by [undistort](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort) and [undistortPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints)